# ERROR Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a problem in installing vm on KVM using libvirt `virsh install`

```
sudo virt-install -n ccnx1 -r 512 --vcpus=1 --os-type=linux --accelerate --nographics -v -l ~/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-i386.iso --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test.img,size=5 -x "console=ttyS0"
```

The output of console `ERROR    Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'`

Before installing qemu 1.2.0, (for using qemu-img), installing VM works well, but after installing qemu, above output was generated

My kvm version is **QEMU emulator version 1.0 (qemu-kvm-1.0)**

virsh capabilities

```
<capabilities>    

  <host>
    <uuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-00259091d77a</uuid>
    <cpu>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
      <model>Westmere</model>
      <vendor>Intel</vendor>
      <topology sockets='1' cores='4' threads='1'/>
      <feature name='rdtscp'/>
      <feature name='pdpe1gb'/>
      <feature name='x2apic'/>
      <feature name='dca'/>
      <feature name='xtpr'/>
      <feature name='tm2'/>
      <feature name='est'/>
      <feature name='vmx'/>
      <feature name='ds_cpl'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='pbe'/>
      <feature name='tm'/>
      <feature name='ht'/>
      <feature name='ss'/>
      <feature name='acpi'/>
      <feature name='ds'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
    </cpu>
    <power_management>
      <suspend_mem/>
      <suspend_disk/>
      <suspend_hybrid/>
    </power_management>
    <migration_features>
      <live/>
      <uri_transports>
        <uri_transport>tcp</uri_transport>
      </uri_transports>
    </migration_features>
    <topology>
      <cells num='1'>
        <cell id='0'>
          <cpus num='4'>
            <cpu id='0'/>
            <cpu id='1'/>
            <cpu id='2'/>
            <cpu id='3'/>
          </cpus>
        </cell>
      </cells>
    </topology>
    <secmodel>
      <model>apparmor</model>
      <doi>0</doi>
    </secmodel>
  </host>

</capabilities>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that `kvm` and `kvm_intel` are loaded (`lsmod |grep kvm`)
2. If they aren't loaded, try to `modprobe` them
3. If that fails, check your BIOS, CPU flags will show capabilities but not what is actually ernabled or not. You should have VT enabled, and if you find it disabled, make sure you don't just enable it but also run a full power cycle of the server.

Comment: and what if they are loaded?